# min persons max persons fields validation with jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In my form, i am allowing to enter Minimum persons and maximum persons in textbox. I have put validation with min parameter that it should be minimum 1. But how can i put validation that minimum persons field should also be less then maximum persons and vise versa. Also minimum persons and maximum persons both should not be same. Can anybody help how can i do this? Thanks in advance!

```
$("#frmCont").validate({
        rules:{
            name:{ required:true},
            min_persons:{ digits:true,min:1 },
            max_persons:{ digits:true,min:1 },
            duration:{ digits:true,min:1 },
            price_per_person:{ digits:true,min:1 }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You have an extra set of closing brackets here `});`

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup?  Help us to help you.

Comment: How can `max_persons` possibly have a `min` of `1` if `min_persons` is not allowed to be zero?

Answer (score 0):

You would write a function that returns the parameter of the rule, which makes it dependent upon the value or state of another field.

```
$("#frmCont").validate({
    rules: {
        min_persons: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('[name="max_persons"]').is(':filled');
            },
            digits: true,
            min: 1
        },
        max_persons: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('[name="min_persons"]').is(':filled');
            },
            digits: true,
            min: function(element) {
                return parseInt($('[name="min_persons"]').val()) + 1;
            }
        },
        ....
```

1. Each field is only `required` if the other field is filled out.
2. The parameter for the `min` rule on the `max_persons` field is determined by the value of the `min_persons` field.
3. The two fields can never be equal since there is a `min` rule on one of the fields that is always going to be one number greater than the other field.

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/vxtjbqod/](https://jsfiddle.net/vxtjbqod/)**